# Android switch VideoView orientation from Portrait to Landscape without stretching the video horizontally

Tags: android, video

I have an application that play video from the external storage. The videos look fine in portrait mode, but they are stretched in landscape mode. Is there any easy way to set the landscape mode video playback width to fit the video ?

this is my video playing activity:

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {

    private VideoView video;
    private MediaController controller;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);
        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vwPlayVideo);
        controller = new MediaController(this);

        video.setOnCompletionListener(this);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            String videoPath = extras.getString("videoPath");
            video.setVideoPath(videoPath);
            controller.setMediaPlayer(video);
            video.setMediaController(controller);
            video.requestFocus();
            video.start();

            if(savedInstanceState != null){
                video.seekTo(savedInstanceState.getInt("currentPos"));
            }
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if(video.isPlaying()){
            outState.putInt("currentPos", video.getCurrentPosition());
        }   
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

edit: activity_play_video.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vwPlayVideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show us your xml pls!

Comment: try wrap_content for both, width and height of the VideoView.

Comment: hey thanks, that did it! Also added gravity="center" to align it better. I figured it was easy, although, I thought it would be a bit more code than that :P Add it as an answer and I'll accept it. @wutk3ks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .xml try the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vwPlayVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will not change the videoratio.
To make the VideoView fill the whole screen, try the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <VideoView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:alignParentTop="true"
          android:alignParentLeft="true"
          android:alignParentRight="true"
          android:alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```